# Background GCM Push Notification Not Received on Certain Apple Devices

Tags: ios, notifications, google-cloud-messaging

I have my iOS app set up to receive push notifications via GCM.  Having set everything up, I am able to receive notifications when the app is in the foreground on various Apple devices.  However, when the app is in the background, I only receive push notifications for *certain* devices, namely only my iPhone 6.  Other devices, such as an iPhone 5s and an iPod Touch are only able to capture notifications when the app is in the foreground.

I looked into other people's questions regarding this issue, bug I have yet to see one that is device model specific.  Often it comes down to not setting the `content_available: true` setting, but I have it set.  Here is an example of a payload I am using:

```
{
    "to":".....",
    "content_available":true,
    "notification": {
            "title":"my title",
            "body":"my body",
            "sound":"default"
    }
}
```

I receive this background notification exactly how I'd want to on my iPhone 6 (my phone is woken and I see a banner), but other devices (which are also using iOS v8.4.1) do not respond to the notification when the app is in the background.

Other details:

- I am using Enterprise build
- I am using the production APN server (and specify so in the GCM registration options)
- Although I don't think it's necessary, I have all the devices registered with my Apple developer account.

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You should add the `priority` parameter to your request. For example

```
{
    "to":".....",
    "content_available":true,
    "priority": "high", // Add this field corresponds to 10 for APNS
    "notification": {
            "title":"my title",
            "body":"my body",
            "sound":"default"
    } 
}
```

Here is the [GCM reference](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref) that mentions the `priority` field. In case you do not set the priority level the message is sent via `Normal` priority which in APNS's case is highly variable.

Comment: Thanks for the advice.  My company decided against using GCM for iOS since we were only using downstream messaging anyway, so I can't currently test out your solution.  However, for what it's worth, I had never tried setting the **priority** parameter, so it's possible it would have solved it for me.

Comment: I got a chance today to see if this would solved my issue and it did.  Just wanted to confirm to anyone who had my issue that this field made the difference.  Thanks!

Comment: Thanks. this works for me also, but just to note. You need both _**content_available:true**_, and _**priority:high**_ for it to work. And still, this will not affect delivery to Android devices.