# Push notification in iOS app when "Not running" state

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I working with GCM Push notifications in my iOS app. The problem is, when user killed this app by the switch up in task manager. If the user do this then notifications wasn't display on screen. How can I fix this? I know about PushKit framework but I interested for example how gmail do this in iOS 6 or 7?

Comment: The way gmail and other apps do it is actually (mostly) via an outside service. Gmail's servers sends a special message to an Apple server, called the APN, that iOS devices are communicating with, which will trigger a notification that (internally) holds enough data to point the gmail app itself to the right information.

Comment: Can I implement this in my app in some way?

Comment: No, not directly from your application. You can send notifications if the app is in the background, but if they "swipe up" or the system ends the task, you have to register an external notification provider, which is usually some sort of server posting to Apple.

Comment: So in iOS 8+ most covenient way is implement PushKit? But what about iOS 7? I using Google Cloud Messaging.

Comment: PushKit is fine, and Google Cloud Messaging is an excellent implementation of what I was describing above, with an external server handling push notifications.

Comment: Hm.. how can I receive push notification alert when app is in "Not running" state with GCM? It is possible?

Comment: @Aleks Yes it is possible. That is what Push notifications are for. If you're able to receive a downstream message from GCM in the foreground it should theoretically work even when your app is not active (suspended or killed).  You might be setting your priority incorrectly. See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32410292/background-gcm-push-notification-not-received-on-certain-apple-devices/32467419#32467419

Also you should tell us what's the message you're trying to send.

Comment: Thank you! The priority option work fine!

Comment: Yeah, to further what @evanescent was saying, a small part of your app will be woken on a background thread when the push notification arrives, which is nice. Are you still having issues with background notifications, or did we resolve it for you?

Comment: @Aleks can you add the answer and accept it, that should close the question and be more easily searchable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution for the problem is to set the "priority" to "high" in push notification json.