# GCM IOS device not registered

Tags: ios, google-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications

I try to send APN using GCM. Device is registered OK, GCM and IOS device tokens are received.
When I try to send payload without "notification" node:

```
{
"to":"GCM TOKEN",   
    "data":{
          "message": "TEST",
          "feed_id": 121,
    }
}
```

Everything works fine.

```
{"multicast_id":4767627754343692164,"success":1,"failure":0,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"message_id":"0:1455817174655839%663656d2f9fd7ecd"}]}
```

But I want to handle notification when application is in background

```
func application( application: UIApplication,
        didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject],
        fetchCompletionHandler handler: (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void)
```

According to the documentation, I modify payload to:

```
{       
   "to":"GCM TOKEN",   
   "notification" : {
      "body" : "great match!",
      "title" : "Portugal vs. Denmark",
      "icon" : "myicon"
    },
    "data":{
          "message": "TEST",
          "feed_id": 121,
    }
 }
```

first attempt:

```
{"multicast_id":4864342605467955143,"success":1,"failure":0,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"message_id":"0:1455817367467043%663656d2663656d2"}]}
```

But notification are not received.

Second attempt:

```
{"multicast_id":8013376855048129620,"success":0,"failure":1,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"error":"NotRegistered"}]}
```

And then application does not receive any notification,even when I remove notification node. So I have to remove it, and reinstall, receive new tokens.

Second issue:

I tried to check APN using NWPusher, but get error: invalid token.
token example:

```
<dab5efc5 42af7327 c2541cb1 06d023c5 2bd4ac44 7a78c8c9 47ea33a6 76f3ffd3>
```

But for registering in GCM this token is OK, why?

Comment: possibly similar issue - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32410292/background-gcm-push-notification-not-received-on-certain-apple-devices hopefully this can solve your issue as well. It indicates that you set the `priority` attribute to high.

Comment: Any solution for this issue? Encountering the same symptoms and the priority solution suggested here does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason of my issue was the absence  of the Provisioning Profile.

[**EDIT** to elaborate on this]:

It looks like a problem with the provisioning of the app on device.
To get push and background notifications working again:

- remove the application from the test device
- perform 'clean' in XCode
- perform 'build' in XCode
- reinstall the app to the device

Comment: Can you elaborate on this?